# model validation rule starts with and ends with

Tags: c#, regex, validation, data-annotations

I need to add a validator to a property of a class that enforces the following:

must start with "TR" OR "WE" and end with a 3-4 digit number. I have additional validating rules such as length and required but can't figure out how to enforce the one outlined above. I suspect I have to regex in someway but I'm not sure of the syntax.

```
public string Tree { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
[RegularExpression("^(TR|WE)[a-z,A-Z]*[0-9]{3,4}$")]
public string Tree { get; set; }
```

You can read the docs for examples/more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can alter [a-z,A-Z]* to match your requirements in terms of what characters are allowed in the middle of the string

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I'm going to have to read up on that. I appreciate the links.